# Find Out List Of Objects Referenced In Snowflake Procedure

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to get list of Objects referenced in Snowflake Procedure , let us say It is using Tables, Views Inside it , I want to find those items from Procedure definition , as currently there is no function in Snowflake that can provide this information.
GET_OBJECT_REFERENCES https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/get_object_references.html is function now only available for Views and not for Procedure.
Any pointers in scanning the definition of Procedure and figure out objects in it.

Comment: I believe the DESCRIBE command can be used to review the SP's as detailed here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/desc-procedure.html 

Also, this reference link is a good pointer: https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D50Z00009Gvzb2SAB/how-to-view-code-of-snowflake-stored-procedures-in-order-to-modify-them-or-look-for-an-error

Comment: It's almost impossible to know what objects a stored procedure will reference before running it, because the store procedure can have arbitrary code creating arbitrary sql queries to be executed. How do you plan to work around this?

Comment: Hi @Felipe Hoffa , may be because of SNOWFLAKE JavaScript Based Procedure there is restriction here , once we have SQL Based Procedure introduced in Snowflake , is GET_OBJECTS_REFERNCES would be enhanced to support Procedure as Input argument to determine its dependent objects;

Comment: The problem is that arbitrary code can create random queries when executed. What if that query picks tables at random?

Comment: @FelipeHoffa "It's almost impossible to know what objects a stored procedure will reference before running it" Isn't that true in context for JS/Java or dynamic SQL stored procedures? With SQL as language for stored procedure it should be no longer the limitation(my guess) as "static code" could  be validated for object existstence(the same way as table-valued functions)

Answer (score 0):

As Felipe pointed out, you can pass the name of a table or view as a parameter into the stored procedure. In that case there's no way to know what objects the SP will reference.

If your organization tends not to do that; if your SQL in stored procedures tends to be more along the lines of `"select * from my_table"` you can simply search for those references in the stored procedure code.

The following statement is crude, but effective. It could be developed and polished a lot, and it could miss references. It also only finds the first match, while a more useful query would return all and flatten out the array. I may have time to work on that a bit. It did find a lot in my test. It simply looks for the following pattern:

```
SQL Command ... Matching Clause for that Command ... Semicolon
```

The reason this works is that even if you don't terminate the SQL in the stored procedure, the JavaScript line should be terminated with a semicolon. JavaScript is comparatively forgiving of missing semicolons, but it should hit one eventually and match the SQL statement.

```
select   PROCEDURE_CATALOG
        ,PROCEDURE_SCHEMA
        ,PROCEDURE_NAME
        ,ARGUMENT_SIGNATURE
        ,regexp_substr(PROCEDURE_DEFINITION, 'SELECT\\s.*FROM.*;|INSERT\\s.*INTO.*;|UPDATE\\s.*SET.*;|MERGE\\s.*INTO.*;|DELETE\\s.*FROM.*;|MERGE\\s.*USING.*;',1, 1, 'ims') STATEMENT
from    MY_DATABASE.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCEDURES
where   STATEMENT is not null;
```

I write a lot of stored procedures, and to Felipe's point this returns a lot of rows like this for me:

```
select ${params.leftColumnList} from ${params.leftObject} order by ${leftTimestamp};`);
```

In those cases, you'd need to have someone who can read code figure out what it's referencing. In this case, the SP accepts parameters for those fields, so they could be any tables.

Comment: thank your Sir for shedding the light on this feature ,  let me try this query , i think most of scenarios in my Procedure definitions should cover this;  thanks again , appreciate your efforts here.

Answer (score 0):

It's currently impossible having dependencies of SPs in Snowflake (and having to build your own parser is not a reasonable workaround). It's a pity that Snowflake does not have the feature of dependencies for stored-procedures. That feature exists in Microsoft SQL Server, and I have used it for building automated lineage documentation of the data warehouses I am working on. It should not be impossible for Snowflake to offer that feature....