# Object Dependency of snowflake stored procedure

Tags: database, stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, etl

I need a way to get the list of all dependent table or base table which is been used in the snowflake stored procedure

get_refernce_object function give the list of dependent object but that is only for views

Comment: Hi, what is the query that you are using to get the result, did you check if you have access on the view snowflake.account_usage.object_dependencies

Comment: I m using below query to get the dependency but still no luck.                          
SELECT *
FROM SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.OBJECT_DEPENDENCIES
WHERE REFERENCED_SCHEMA = 'SCHEMA'
  AND REFERENCED_OBJECT_NAME = 'EMP_PROC'

Comment: Do you get any rows , can you remove the filter criteria  REFERENCED_SCHEMA = 'SCHEMA' and see if you get any rows

Comment: tried with below query but still 0 rows SELECT *
FROM SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.OBJECT_DEPENDENCIES
WHERE 
--REFERENCED_SCHEMA = 'SCHEMA'
   REFERENCED_OBJECT_NAME = 'EMP_PROC'

Comment: Looks like the role that you are using dose not have access to the function, try to create one simple object and see if you are seeing in  OBJECT_DEPENDENCIES .

Comment: Its not related to role issue.
OBJECT_DEPENDENCIES fn cannot run on Procedure.
select distinct referenced_object_domain from snowflake.account_usage.object_dependencies;

Comment: HI , this this link  where it looks into the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCEDURES view and get the result, may be this could work for you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69039629/find-out-list-of-objects-referenced-in-snowflake-procedure